# How can i get information in Network Payload using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I receive information from another page from a payment processor. On the admin panel I can assign the page where it will end its process and redirect there. When I check this final page I use as a response page.

I can see all important information when I enter in Chrome Devtools --> Network --> Payload

How can I get this info in CodeBehind on `Page_load`?

I tried using `request.form.allkeys` but didn't return anything.

Here is an example of what I see:

[image: Chrome devtools showing the payload for a network request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the error.

If you are using FriendlyUrls on ASP.NET the url you set on your payment processor must not have the **".aspx"** extension for the page where is it supposed to receive the info.

After i made the correction i could see the parameters using:

Request.Form["name_of_parameter"]

Answer (score 0):

When using `FriendlyUrls` on ASP.NET, the URL you set on your payment processor must not have the ".aspx" extension for the page where is it supposed to receive the info.

```
Public Shared Function GetRequestBody() As String
    Dim bodyStream = New IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
    bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    Dim _payload = bodyStream.ReadToEnd()
    Return _payload
End Function
```